# Запятая перед распространенным согласованным определением

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

Строители Красноярской ГЭС краном опускали за плотину большую металлическую решетку и поднимали ее (,) полную крупных рыбин.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Запятая не нужна:**

Строители Красноярской ГЭС краном опускали за плотину большую металлическую решетку и поднимали ее **полную крупных рыбин**.

Розенталь 2. **Не обособляются распространенные определения**: 3) связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, в состав которого они входят: Море у его ног лежало безмолвное и белое от облачного неба (Пауст.); Автобусы шли битком набитые.

В данном случае оборот относится не к подлежащему, а к дополнению, но принцип тот же самый: отсутствие паузы, тесная связь с определяемым словом.

Comment: Спасибо большое.